# Pexpect - Wait to finish a command before continue

Tags: python, pexpect

I have a current situation with pexpect.

```py
child = pexpect.spawn(f"virsh console {hostname} --force", timeout=200, maxread=4000)

child.sendline("sudo config ztp disable -y")
child.send("\r")
print(" Waiting ZTP ")
sleep(120)
# rest of my script
```

This command can take 1-2min to finish, now I'm doing a sleep after it "sleep(120)"

I would like to know if there is a way to perform it using pexpect arguments instead of sleep, so I can continue my pexect script as soon as the disable command finishes instead of having a fixed sleep time.

Comment: `pexpect.run('command')` will run the command and wait for it to finish.

Comment: In general, the typical approach when you're starting a child with `sendline()` -- meaning the running process is a shell -- is to `expect()` the prompt that prints when the child is finished. Maybe configure that prompt to be something extra unambiguous.

Comment: the run does't work for me once it's a console connection in a virtual environment, so I'm using spawn.

Comment: @bgrbr2016, what's the prompt on that console? Expect to see that prompt printed again when the command is done.

Comment: Anyhow -- I can't answer this unless I know what the remote prompt is. That question wasn't just asked for purposes of amusement.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I've just added an answer to this post once the output is a bit big and there is a character restriction for comment.

Comment: Okay, so the prompt I was asking for is `admin@sonic:~$`. Didn't need the whole output, just that one line.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I tried to put it as child.expect however it didn't work. my script moves forward after the child.sendline("sudo config ztp disable -y"). The only thing that I could do so far was configure a sleep(XX) to wait a bit more, but it's not a good way once I would like to be sure the ZTP process fished before go.

Comment: BTW, note that `pexpect.spawn(f"virsh console {hostname}"` has some security bugs if someone could tell your software to treat, say, `$(rm -rf ~)` as a hostname. It's always safer to use `shlex.quote()` on content before substituting it into somewhere it'll be treated as code by a shell.

Comment: hi @CharlesDuffy, many thanks so far but unfortunately it didn't work either, the script don't wait and move to the next steps as you can see below. 

root@lab:~# python3.7 test_console.py
------------------------------------------------------------
- test_sonic_4: Disabling Sonic ZTP
- test_sonic_4: ZTP Finished
- test_sonic_4: Leaving Console
- test_sonic_4: ZTP disabled - completed
------------------------------------------------------------
I've just posted the entire conde I'm trying to perform, perhaps it can help.

Comment: pexpect has debug tracing you can enable so it'll tell you which string matched the pattern it's waiting for. That's always a good place to start when it's matching earlier than you expect.

Comment: Beyond that, the best way to permit a definitive answer would be to provide a [MRE] people without this "ZTP" tool can run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using waitnoecho(), it worked for my case. [Here](http://www.bx.psu.edu/%7Enate/pexpect/pexpect.html) is the link for the docs. Share with me if you found different working solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
admin@sonic:~$ sudo config ztp disable -y
Running command: ztp disable -y
May 26 08:20:45.302973+00:00 2022 sonic WARNING sonic-ztp[2858]: Received terminate signal. Shutting down.
[  131.941412] e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth1: Reset adapter
[  132.053160] e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth1: Reset adapter
[  132.105350] e1000 0000:00:04.0 eth2: Reset adapter
[  132.165155] e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth1: Reset adapter
[  132.311991] e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth1: Reset adapter
[  132.317174] e1000 0000:00:05.0 eth3: Reset adapter
[  132.505185] e1000 0000:00:06.0 eth4: Reset adapter

May 26 08:20:56.865683 System is not ready - one or more services are not up
[  237.895018] e1000 0000:00:05.0 eth3: Reset adapter
Waiting for system online status before stopping ZTP. (This may take 30--180 seconds).
Removing ZTP configuration profile. Loading factory default configuration.
Platform and HWSKU Valid - /usr/share/sonic/device/x86_64-kvm_x86_64-r0/DellEMC-S5248f-P-25G-DPB
Running command: /usr/local/bin/db_migrator.py -o check_version -f /etc/sonic/config_db.json
Stopping SONiC target ...
Stopping service bgp.service ...
Stopping service caclmgrd.service ...
Stopping service dhcp_relay.service ...
Stopping service gbsyncd.service ...
Stopping service hostcfgd.service ...
Stopping service iccpd.service ...
Stopping service l2mcd.service ...
Stopping service lldp.service ...
Stopping service macsec.service ...
Stopping service mgmt-framework.service ...
Stopping service mgmt-framework.timer ...
Stopping service nat.service ...
Stopping service pmon.service ...
Stopping service portinitdone.service ...
Stopping service procdockerstatsd.service ...
Stopping service radv.service ...
Stopping service rsyslog-config.service ...
Stopping service sflow.service ...
Stopping service stp.service ...
Stopping service swss.service ...
Stopping service syncd.service ...
Stopping service tam.service ...
Stopping service teamd.service ...
Stopping service telemetry.timer ...
Stopping service udld.service ...
Stopping service vrrp.service ...
Services are stopped

Running command: queuestat -D
Running command: /usr/local/bin/sonic-cfggen -j /etc/sonic/copp_config.json --write-to-db
Running command: /usr/local/bin/sonic-cfggen -j /etc/sonic/init_cfg.json --write-to-db
Running command: /usr/local/bin/sonic-cfggen -j /etc/sonic/config_db.json --write-to-db
upgrade: Migrating Conifg DB from version_4_0_1 to version_4_0_1
Running command: /usr/local/bin/sonic-cfggen -d -y /etc/sonic/sonic_version.yml -t /usr/share/sonic/templates/sonic-environment.j2,/etc/sonic/sonic-environment
Resetting failed status on bgp.service
Resetting failed status on caclmgrd.service
Resetting failed status on dhcp_relay.service
Resetting failed status on gbsyncd.service
Resetting failed status on hostcfgd.service
Resetting failed status on hostname-config.service
Resetting failed status on iccpd.service
Resetting failed status on interfaces-config.service
Resetting failed status on l2mcd.service
Resetting failed status on lacp_helper.service
Resetting failed status on lldp.service
Resetting failed status on macsec.service
Resetting failed status on mgmt-framework.service
Resetting failed status on mgmt-framework.timer
Resetting failed status on nat.service
Resetting failed status on ntp-config.service
Resetting failed status on pmon.service
Resetting failed status on portinitdone.service
Resetting failed status on procdockerstatsd.service
Resetting failed status on radv.service
Resetting failed status on rsyslog-config.service
Resetting failed status on sflow.service
Resetting failed status on stp.service
Resetting failed status on swss.service
Resetting failed status on syncd.service
Resetting failed status on tam.service
Resetting failed status on teamd.service
Resetting failed status on telemetry.timer
Resetting failed status on udld.service
Resetting failed status on vrrp.service
Restarting SONiC target ...
Starting service bgp.service ...
Starting service caclmgrd.service ...
Starting service dhcp_relay.service ...
Starting service gbsyncd.service ...
Starting service hostcfgd.service ...
Starting service iccpd.service ...
Starting service l2mcd.service ...
Starting service lldp.service ...
Starting service macsec.service ...
Starting service mgmt-framework.service ...
Starting service mgmt-framework.timer ...
Starting service nat.service ...
Starting service pmon.service ...
Starting service portinitdone.service ...
Starting service procdockerstatsd.service ...
Starting service radv.service ...
Starting service rsyslog-config.service ...
Starting service sflow.service ...
Starting service stp.service ...
Starting service swss.service ...
Starting service syncd.service ...
Starting service tam.service ...
Starting service teamd.service ...
Starting service telemetry.timer ...
Starting service udld.service ...
Starting service vrrp.service ...
Services are started

Reloading Monit configuration ...
Reinitializing monit daemon
Reload complete!
Verifying if core services have started
admin@sonic:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `expect()` to watch the output of your command and wait for the prompt that follows its successful completion.

```
from shlex import quote
prompt = 'admin@sonic:~[$]'

child = pexpect.spawn(f"virsh console {quote(hostname)} --force", timeout=200, maxread=4000)

# wait until we see the first prompt before sending that command
# that way we can't match that prompt later and think the process finished early
child.expect(prompt)

child.sendline("sudo config ztp disable -y")
child.send("\r")
print(" Waiting ZTP ")

# Wait for the prompt again; this one will only match the one from _after_
# the command finishes execution, because we already matched the one from before
child.expect(prompt)
print(" Finished waiting for ZTP ")
```